# How do I make the triangular side areas increase and decrease on an icosahedron without the shape remaining "intact"?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, geometry, visualization

How would I go about making an icosahedron rotate as well as the triangular sides increase in area, as seen in the video here: [Click here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPqTCrm61-I)

Here is a JavaScript code using THREE.js

> THREE.IcosahedronGeometry = function ( radius, detail ) {
>
> var t = ( 1 + Math.sqrt( 5 ) ) / 2;
>
> var vertices = [
>         - 1,  t,  0,    1,  t,  0,   - 1, - t,  0,    1, - t,  0,        0, - 1,  t,    0,  1,  t,    0, - 1, - t,    0,  1, - t,        t,  0, - 1,    t, 
>   0,  1,   - t,  0, - 1,   - t,  0,  1  ];
>
> var indices = [          0, 11,  5,    0,  5,  1,    0,  1,  7,    0,  7,
>   10,    0, 10, 11,          1,  5,  9,    5, 11,  4,   11, 10,  2,   10,  7, 
>   6,    7,  1,  8,       3,  9,  4,    3,  4,  2,    3,  2,  6,    3,  6, 
>   8,    3,  8,  9,       4,  9,  5,    2,  4, 11,    6,  2, 10,    8,  6, 
>   7,    9,  8,  1   ];
>
> THREE.PolyhedronGeometry.call( this, vertices, indices, radius,
>   detail );
>
> this.type = 'IcosahedronGeometry';
>
> this.parameters = {         radius: radius,         detail: detail  }; };
>
> THREE.IcosahedronGeometry.prototype = Object.create(
>   THREE.Geometry.prototype );

It is by timothypratley / https://github.com/timothypratley

Answer (score 0):

To scale up and down in position, each triangle will need to be constructed with points centered around zero. To center a triangle on zero we find the midpoint of the 3 vertices, and subtract that from each of the points. Now the triangle can be scaled without moving away from the origin.

The triangles are then added to a parent object, and positioned at the midpoint we calculated earlier. Thus when the triangles are scaled, they are scaled relative to their position in the icosahedron shape.

Here is the code to construct the disjoint triangles:

```
(defn icos []
  (let [icosahedron (js/THREE.Object3D.)]
    (doseq [triangle indices
            :let [vs (map vertices triangle)
                  [x y z :as face-center] (map average (transpose vs))
                  normalized-vertices (for [v vs]
                                        (map - v face-center))
                  face-mesh (geo normalized-vertices)]]
      (.set (.-position face-mesh) x y z)
      (.add icosahedron face-mesh))
    icosahedron))
```

For each triangle, look up its vertices. Find the face center. Subtract the face center from each vertex. Create the geometry. Position the geometry at the face center relative to the icosahedron. You can see the [full rendering code on github](https://github.com/timothypratley/icopop/blob/master/src/cljs/icopop/renderbox.cljs).

The final result: [Icopop](https://icopop.herokuapp.com/) allows you to scale the triangles or the icosahedron while it spins.